# SPARQL filter lang 'en' gives other languages

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

The following SPARQL query doesn't get the results I want because they are in other languages than English, regardless of the `filter lang 'en'` (see filters in query).

Results of the query :

```
"Никола́й Ива́нович Буха́рин"@en    "Никола́й Буха́рин"@en  "Nikolai Bukharin"@en
"Gamal Abdel Nasser Hussein"@en     "جمال عبد الناصر"@en    "Gamal Abdel Nasser"@en
```

I looked at the DBpedia page and I saw that there is the English version of the names, but I don't see why the filter doesn't work !!!

Can someone help me with that ?

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?birthname ?nameExact ?label
where {

     ?person rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person .
     ?person rdfs:label ?label .
     OPTIONAL { ?person dbpedia-owl:birthName ?birthname . }
     OPTIONAL { ?person dbpprop:name ?nameExact . }

     FILTER (lang(?birthname) = 'en')
     FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en')
     FILTER (lang(?nameExact) = 'en')

}
LIMIT 300
```

Answer (score 10):

Be careful, to prefix, you must use the same in declaration and query (`dbo` -> `dbo`, not `dbo` -> `dbpedia-owl`)

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?birthname ?nameExact ?label
where {

     ?person rdf:type dbo:Person .
     ?person rdfs:label ?label .
     OPTIONAL { ?person dbo:birthName ?birthname . }
     OPTIONAL { ?person dbp:name ?nameExact . }

     FILTER (lang(?birthname) = 'en')
     FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en')
     FILTER (lang(?nameExact) = 'en')

}

LIMIT 300
```

Answer (score 7):

The language tag is an annotation in the database. Your filter works correctly. Some of the values in the database are annotated with `en` even though they are in different scripts. You'll need to write your own logic that selects the most appropriate property. I'd probably just use the `rdfs:label` property and cut off anything in brackets (like in `"Black Hawk (Sauk leader)"@en`). That seems to provide decent results.

Also note that you need to put the `FILTER`s for `?birthname` and `?nameExact` *into* the respective `OPTIONAL` block, otherwise they will end up removing any matches that didn't have the optional property.